# How to use placeholders in like clause in SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, parameters, parameter-passing, prepared-statement

This is my query:

```
 select * from Table1 where Identifier = 'ABC' and Identifier_Type like ':name%:id'
```

can I change this to,

```
 select * from Table1 where Identifier = 'ABC' and Identifier_Type like '?%?'
```

will it work? I have to use these parameters in the prepared statement so I thought of replacing the named parameters with the placeholders `'?'`.. will it work like this `'?%?'`

Comment: Why you asking here if it will work :D just try to check it first on your own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Should be like this::

```
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement ("Select * 
    from 
    Table1 where Identifier = 'ABC' and Identifier_Type  like?");
```

While setting in prepared statement:

```
   pstmt.setString(1, "%" + data + "%"); // where data is string Variable
```

OR By using SQL function

```
   PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
  "select * from Table1 where Identifier = 'ABC' and Identifier_Type  
    like  CONCAT( '%',?,'%')";
     
     pstmt.setString(1, data); // Where data is String variable
```

Comment: Your first solution is vulnerable to SQL Intejection attacks.

Comment: Your second solution works for me in H2 Database Engine. And this approach should resist SQL Injection attacks. Thank you!